# Retrieve access token for App service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, botframework

I currently have a Bot for MS Teams that I have created in Visual studio. I need a way of retrieving the information of the user of the Bot in MS Teams when they have used it such as the email address, full name, etc... This Bot is hosted in Azure as an app service. I have followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-auth-aad and have configured Azure Active Directory authentication on my app service. I have the following code to try and retrieve an access token from Azure that I will then use to get information from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me.

```
static async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetS2SAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(
        resource,  // the resource (app) we are going to access with the token
        clientCredential);  // the client credentials
    return authenticationResult;
}
```

I've taken this code from elsewhere but the problem I'm having is that I can't see a client secret for the Azure Active Directory application and I don't know what "authority" should be. This is my first time working with anything like this so would appreciate any pointers or tips in this area.

---

```
static string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
static string clientId = "my_azure-ad_app_id";
static string resource = "https://<app_name>.azurewebsites.net/";
static string clientSecret = "azure-ad_app_secret";

static public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetS2SAccessTokenForProdMSAAsync()
{
    return await GetS2SAccessToken(authority, resource, clientId, clientSecret);
}

static async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetS2SAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string clientSecret)
{
    var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(
        resource,  // the resource (app) we are going to access with the token
        clientCredential);  // the client credentials
    return authenticationResult;
}
```

This is the code I've got to retrieve the access token so far but it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The secret (or key) you can get by generating one in its App Registration blade. You should go to Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Find your app -> Keys -> Enter a name, select duration and Save.
You should now have your key.

The authority is basically "the identity provider we will authenticate against".
So if your app is only meant for use in your organization,
you'll want to specify that AAD tenant.
In that case the authority would be:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-tenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

Replace `your-tenant.onmicrosoft.com` with any verified domain name you have in AAD (one in this format is included always), or use your AAD tenant id instead (you can find it from AAD -> Properties).

In case your app should support any organization (i.e. it's a multi-tenant app),
then the authority is always:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common
```

Comment: So would the resource in my case be "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me" as this is what I wish to access with the access token with in order to get the information from it via a HTTP GET request?

Comment: The resource is basically the identifier for the API you want to call. In the case of MS Graph API, the identifier is `https://graph.microsoft.com`. The endpoint you call there does not matter. This URI identifies the API. You can also find this URI for your APIs from App registration -> Properties -> App ID URI.

Comment: So this App ID URI, I had to change this before in order to enable Multi-tenanted for the Azure Authentication application. I read somewhere that it should be something like this https://<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com/<name of app> and so I changed it to this value but this URL doesn't work. Is this what the resource should be set to? I have provided more code above if that helps in determining where I might be going wrong. Thanks so far!

Comment: Yeah, so with multi-tenanted apps, I do believe the format of the URI should be what you said. Though nowadays if you create an app, the URI is in the correct format immediately (though it uses a GUID instead of the app name). And no, it does not have to be the URL of the app. It is an identifier (notice it is a URI, not a URL).

Comment: If you want to call Microsoft Graph API, you need to set the resource to `https://graph.microsoft.com`. This tells AAD that you want an access token for MS Graph. If you instead wanted to call another API, you'd have to specify their identifier instead. Note that this is because an access token is only valid for one API.

Comment: Aha I now have the access token being returned to me now but now when I run the HTTP GET request to "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users" I get an error, "Authorization_IdentityNotFound". As I have tried to configure a multi-tenanted application should it matter that the bot is being used by a user from another Azure Active Directory? So I have logged into MS Teams using an email account from Azure Active Directory "A" but I have the bot held in Azure Active Directory "B", should this prove an issue and cause the error that I have got?

Comment: You might need to specify the tenant id explicitly in the authority URL. So instead of `common`, use Directory B's tenant id or verified domain name. Using common + client credentials will probably always get you an access token for Directory A.

Comment: So this has worked, however it returned the user credentials of the only user from AD "B". My authority URI is now set to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant name>.onmicrosoft.com", which is representative of AD "B". The user logged into MS Teams is from AD "A" and so as a test what I have done is to change the graph end point to be "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/AD-A-User-Object-Id" and having run a HTTP GET request against this I get the following error "Resource <user id> does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present".

Comment: Now I would normally expect this but having set up my application to be multi-tenanted I thought that this would work. With the expectancy that this Bot will be used by users from AD's outside of my domain (A and B), should I reconsider the Authentication Provider in the "Authentication/Authorization" section of my app service?

Comment: A token is also only valid for a single AAD tenant. So if you want to access data from A, you need to get the token from A.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Junnas Answer. You can try this [reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#get-application-id-and-authentication-key)

**Client Id:**

[image]

**Client Secret :**

[image]

*Note: The Client Secret is visible only at the time of creation. After that, it won't appear again. So make sure you copy on the first time itself*